# How call the CreateOleObject function using dwscript?

Tags: delphi, dwscript

I'm trying to execute this code (this is a minimal sample in order to use CreateOleObject) from inside of a dwscript

```
function GetFileVersion(const FileName: string): string;
var
  V : OleVariant;
begin
  V  := CreateOleObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject');
  Result := V.GetFileVersion(FileName);
end;
```

So far i tried this

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}


uses
  SysUtils,
  ComObj,
  ActiveX,
  dwsComp,
  dwsCompiler,
  dwsExprs,
  dwsCoreExprs;


procedure Execute;
var
  LScript: TDelphiWebScript;
  LUnit: TdwsUnit;
  LProg: IdwsProgram;
  LExec: IdwsProgramExecution;
begin
  LScript := TDelphiWebScript.Create(NIL);
  LUnit := TdwsUnit.Create(NIL);
  try
    LUnit.UnitName := 'Foo';
    LUnit.Script := LScript;
    //  compile a simple script
    LProg := LScript.Compile(
      'function GetFileVersion(const FileName: string): string;'+sLineBreak+
      'var'+sLineBreak+
      '   V : Variant;'+sLineBreak+
      'begin'+sLineBreak+
      ' V  := CreateOleObject(''Scripting.FileSystemObject'');'+sLineBreak+
      ' Result := V.GetFileVersion(FileName);'+sLineBreak+
      'end;'+sLineBreak+
      ''+sLineBreak+
      'PrintLn(GetFileVersion(''Foo''));'+sLineBreak+
      ''
    );

    if LProg.Msgs.HasErrors then begin
      Writeln(LProg.Msgs.AsInfo);
      Exit;
    end;

    try
      LExec := LProg.Execute;
    except
      on E: Exception do
        WriteLn(E.Message + sLineBreak + LExec.Msgs.AsInfo );
    end;
    Writeln(LExec.Result.ToString);
  finally
    LScript.Free;
  end;
end;

begin
  try
    Execute;
    Readln;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

But i'm getting this error message

> Syntax Error: Unknown name "CreateOleObject" [line: 5, column: 8]

the question is how i can execute the [`CreateOleObject`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Win.ComObj.CreateOleObject) function using dwscript?

## UPDATE

Following the [Linas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/205496/linas) suggestions I could finally resolve the issue.

This is a sample working application

```
uses
  SysUtils,
  ComObj,
  ActiveX,
  dwsComp,
  dwsCompiler,
  dwsExprs,
  dwsComConnector,
  dwsCoreExprs;


procedure Execute;
var
  LScript: TDelphiWebScript;
  LUnit: TdwsUnit;
  LProg: IdwsProgram;
  LExec: IdwsProgramExecution;
  LdwsComConnector : TdwsComConnector;
begin
  LScript := TDelphiWebScript.Create(NIL);
  LdwsComConnector:=TdwsComConnector.Create(nil);
  LdwsComConnector.Script:=LScript;
  LUnit := TdwsUnit.Create(NIL);
  try
    LUnit.UnitName := 'Foo';
    LUnit.Script := LScript;
    //  compile a simple script
    LProg := LScript.Compile(
      'function GetFileVersion(const FileName: string): string;'+sLineBreak+
      'var'+sLineBreak+
      '   V : OleVariant;'+sLineBreak+
      'begin'+sLineBreak+
      ' V  := CreateOleObject(''Scripting.FileSystemObject'');'+sLineBreak+
      ' Result := VarToStr(V.GetFileVersion(FileName));'+sLineBreak+
      'end;'+sLineBreak+
      ''+sLineBreak+
      'PrintLn(GetFileVersion(''C:\Bar\Foo.exe''));'+sLineBreak+
      ''
    );

    if LProg.Msgs.HasErrors then begin
      Writeln(LProg.Msgs.AsInfo);
      Exit;
    end;

    try
      LExec := LProg.Execute;
    except
      on E: Exception do
        WriteLn(E.Message + sLineBreak + LExec.Msgs.AsInfo );
    end;
    Writeln(LExec.Result.ToString);
  finally
    LScript.Free;
    LdwsComConnector.Free;
  end;
end;

begin
 try
    CoInitialize(nil);
    try
      Execute;
      Readln;
    finally
      CoUninitialize;
    end;
 except
    on E:Exception do
        Writeln(E.Classname, ':', E.Message);
 end;
end.
```

Comment: I just added that unit, with the same results :(.

Comment: I'm guessing here, but put this uses directive in your file : `uses Windows, Classes, SysUtils, dwsComp, dwsCompiler, dwsExprs,
   dwsComConnector, Variants, ActiveX, ComObj, dwsXPlatform, dwsUtils;`

Comment: See how this unit test is done to use CreateOleObject : [UCOMConnectorTests](http://code.google.com/codesearch#jx8E0zLRzns/trunk/Test/UCOMConnectorTests.pas&q=CreateOleObject%20package:http://dwscript%5C.googlecode%5C.com&ct=rc&cd=2&sq=).

Comment: @LURD, I don't see where `CreateOleObject` gets called from any scripts in that test. It's called in Delphi code to add items to a database.

Comment: @RobKennedy, I think you are absolutely right.

Comment: If you can't use CreateOleObject directly from DWScript, you could create your own "wrapper" function to call it and expose that wrapper function to DWScript... Bit of the long way around I guess, but should work? (Disclaimer: I have only **read** about DWScript).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be accomplished in two ways.

**1 way**: You must drop `TdwsComConnector` (from unit `dwsComConnector`) to your data module or form (or create it manually) and assign your script instance to it. e.g.:

```
dwsComConnector1.Script := LScript;
```

**2 way:**

```
interface

uses
  dwsFunctions, dwsSymbols, dwsExprs;

type
  TCreateOleObjectFunc = class(TInternalFunction)
    procedure Execute(info : TProgramInfo); override;
  end;

implementation

uses 
  OleAuto;

{ TCreateOleObjectFunc }

procedure TCreateOleObjectFunc.Execute(info : TProgramInfo);
begin
  Info.ResultAsVariant := CreateOleObject(Info.ValueAsString['ClassName']);
end;

initialization
  RegisterInternalFunction(TCreateOleObjectFunc, 'CreateOleObject', ['ClassName', cString], cVariant, True);
```

This will expose CreateOleObject function to DWScript so you could use it.

Also you should declare your `V` as `OleVariant` instead of `Variant` and change the line to `Result := VarToStr(V.GetFileVersion(FileName));` to make it work properly.